# Err 0xc0000000e = STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE - A device which does not exist was specified

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012

*Thanks* to [Update on Azure Storage Service Interruption | Microsoft Azure Blog](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/11/19/update-on-azure-storage-service-interruption/), my VM is failed to start (Azure was able to get screenshot).

OS: Windows Server 2012 Datacenter.

[image: Err 0xc0000000e = STATUS_NO_SUCH_DEVICE - A device which does not exist was specified.]

Did anyone on *AZURE* had similar issue? How should I deal with it? (I can attach disk to another VM).

Comment: Boot into recovery mode, select the the recovery console/command prompt and run `bcdedit /enum`. You will probably see that the boot loader and/or boot manager are set to `unknown` or something incorrect, and you need to correct them by using `bcedit /set`.  Let me know what you see/how it goes.

Comment: @HopelessN00b Both `device` and `osdevice` were set to `unknown`. Azure used `bcedit /set` to set correct values, unfortunately that did not help to start Windows, so they're getting another screenshot.